# jQuery Clockpicker afterHourSelect

Tags: jquery

Good morning, this is my first question here in stackoverflow so have mercy ;)

I'm using the [jQuery clockpicker plugin](https://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) for some forms.

It seems, that the usage of the clockpicker is not clear for some of my users. They open the dialog, pick a hour and submit the form without picking a minute in the clockpicker!
If they do so, the input for the time is empty (or is filled with the last used value).
How can I get the selected hour from the clockpicker and put it into my input?

I found out, that there is an `afterHourSelect()` so I think this is what I need. My question is really simple I guess.

```
$('#tTimeFrom".$x."').clockpicker({
    autoclose: true,
    afterHourSelect: function() {
        $('#tTimeFrom".$x."').val( ??? );
    }
});
```

What do I have to write instead of `???` to get the actual selected hour from the clockpicker?

Comment: provide a link to the jquery plugin source code and/or options documentation please. Welcome.

Comment: nothing. write it into a variable: var actTime = $('#tTimeFrom".$x."').val();

Comment: $('#tTimeFrom".$x."').val() is the input field and it's empty.
I need the actual selected hour from the clockpicker and the clockpicker filles the input only if a hour AND a minute is selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your users want to be done when they pick the hours, you can grab the hours value inside the afterHourSelect callback and set the input value with X:00 before they chose minutes. This way if they quit the clockpicker dialogue you will have their input.

```
var end = $('#end').clockpicker({
    afterHourSelect: function() {
        var c = end.data();
        $('#end').val(c.clockpicker.hours + ':00');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh I misunderstood the problem before.

There doesn't seem to be a built in way of doing what you need, but maybe you could guide your users by keeping the clock picker open until a selection is made. You could make the button a different colour too.

Something like:

```
beforeHide: function() {
    if ($('#tTimeFrom".$x."').val == "") {
        $('#tTimeFrom".$x."').show();
        $('.clockpicker-button').addClass("brightRed");
    }
}
```

Comment: The minute would be selected, thats right. But the selected time is not transfered into the input field. That only happens, when the clockpicker is "done".
So I have to manipulate the clockpicker in that way, that the actual value will be written into the input field, after a hour is selected ... I think :(

Comment: I see, thx. Damn, it sounded so easy :(
Your idea is good, but sometimes the input field is allready filled with previous values.
Maybe its the easiest solution if i check all these things after form submit?!? I'm not very into jQuery and it's easier for me to do it with php

Comment: It's faster to validate the form data on the client side. Something simple you could do is add the [required attribute to the input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

(and please accept the answer if it's helpful :D)