# Jquery clockpicker on hide get the time

Tags: jquery, clockpicker

I am using the Jquery clockpicker (https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker). Is there a way that you don't have to push the "Done" button to get the new time in the input field?

I have tried [jQuery Clockpicker afterHourSelect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219838/jquery-clockpicker-afterhourselect) but when I log out the hours and minutes, they are both undefined

Comment: to access to the DOM object of clockpicker is console($('.clockpicker').clockpicker())

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `data-autoclose="true"` and clock picker will close as soon as you select time.

```
<div class="input-group clockpicker" data-placement="left" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

Or you can initialize something like this in javascript:

```
var input = $('#single-input').clockpicker({
    placement: 'bottom',
    align: 'left',
    autoclose: true,
    'default': 'now'
});
```

For more documentation you can refer [here](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/)